# VSTS Release : Create Release using c# NuGet package

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to create/trigger release in VSTS using c# code. I am able create/trigger it using VSTS REST API @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases?view=vsts-rest-4.1

However I would like to know if any NuGet packages are available for creating/triggering/updating release in VSTS using c#?

Comment: Do you mean that creating/triggering/updating release using C# with the Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can also use REST API to create/update release using C#：

Below is an example on how to start a build through the REST API, you can change the parameters and the REST API to create release accordingly: (More information please see : [Accessing TFS/VSTS 2017 programmatically](https://www.domstamand.com/accessing-tfs-2017-programmatically/))

```
var personalaccesstoken = "bXlfc3VwZXJfcGVyc29uYWxfYWNjZXNzX3Rva2Vu";
var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalaccesstoken}"));

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{your_tfs_server}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0");
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definition\": {\"id\":" + definitionId + "},\"sourceBranch\":\"$/BRANCH_NAME\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Besides, if you mean creating/triggering/updating release using Nuget packages in C#, then you can reference the sample mentioned in this blog: [Create a draft release and start it using the TFS REST API](http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2017/07/create-draft-release-and-start-it-using.html)

Reference the code here:

```
var serverUrl = new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com");
var credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", PAT);
var teamProjectName = "[replace with team project name]";

using (var connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, credentials))
using (var rmClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient2>())
using (var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>())
{
    // Get the first build definition
    var releaseDefinition = rmClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(teamProjectName, null, ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Artifacts).Result[0];
    var primaryArtifact = releaseDefinition.Artifacts.Where(a => a.IsPrimary).SingleOrDefault();
    var projectName = primaryArtifact.DefinitionReference["project"].Id;
    var buildDefinitionId = Convert.ToInt32(primaryArtifact.DefinitionReference["definition"].Id);

    // Get the latest successful build from the project and build definition id
    var lastBuild = buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(projectName, new[] { buildDefinitionId }, statusFilter: BuildStatus.Completed).Result
                                .OrderByDescending(b => b.Id)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

    // Create the draft release, and associate it to the latest corresponding build
    var metadata = new ReleaseStartMetadata
    {
        DefinitionId = releaseDefinition.Id,
        IsDraft = true,
        Description = "Draft",
        Artifacts = new[]
        {
            new ArtifactMetadata
            {
                Alias = primaryArtifact.Alias,
                InstanceReference = new BuildVersion
                {
                    Id = lastBuild.Id.ToString(),
                    Name = lastBuild.BuildNumber
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var release = rmClient.CreateReleaseAsync(metadata, teamProjectName).Result;

    // Update the draft release variable
    release.Variables["Variable-A"].Value = "Test A";
    release.Variables["Variable-B"].Value = "Test B";
    release.Environments[0].Variables["Var-Env-A"].Value = "Test C";
    release = rmClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, teamProjectName, release.Id).Result;

    // Activate the release
    var updateMetadata = new ReleaseUpdateMetadata { Status = ReleaseStatus.Active, Comment = "Yeah baby, yeah" };
    release = rmClient.UpdateReleaseResourceAsync(updateMetadata, teamProjectName, release.Id).Result;

    // Trigger the deployment on a specific environment
    release.Environments[0].Status = EnvironmentStatus.InProgress;
    release = rmClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, teamProjectName, release.Id).Result;
```

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you very much for your help!